# UserManager.AddPasswordAsync() returns "Name cannot be null or empty"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I work with MVC5 and ASP.NET identity framework.

I've extended the account manage-functionality which is scaffolded by VS2013.

If my user has registered with an external login provider and wants to add a local password I get and error when I call "AddPasswordAsync()": "Name cannot be null or empty"

I have looked in my db and confirmed that the username is not null.

What does this error mean?

My ApplicationUser looks like this:

```
public class Person : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Sex Sex { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Birth date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
    public string EMail { get; set; }
    public int PostalCode { get; set; }

    public Collection<Race> Races { get; set; }
    public Collection<Participation> Participations { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName))
        {
            UserName = EMail;
        }
        Participations = new Collection<Participation>();
        Races = new Collection<Race>();
        Birthdate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Best regards
Frederik

Comment: What does your `ApplicationUser` class look like?

Comment: I'm sorry I missed this. It's inserted now

Comment: did u solve this issue? I am getting the "Name cannot be null or empty." error as well. I have inserted NAME property to my viewmodel as well but it still gives me this error. If you have solved it, please share with us by posting it as answer. thanks

Comment: Hi Aamir. Alas, I have not solved the problem :(

Answer (score 6):

I finally solved it after a lot of tries. The error message is wrong, it comes from the database and means that username field is null but the database requires it.

Make sure you send the db the user name like that for example:

```
 var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, Hometown = model.Hometown };
```

And make sure that the database is up to date before that by running update-database.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was hoping your `ApplicationUser` would elicit more clues as to what the problem is, but I'm not seeing anything that stands outs. So, here's what advice I can give. It's not asking about `UserName`; it's explicitly saying "Name is required". `AddPasswordAsync` is merely saving the user object to the database, so you need to look deeper and make sure that the *entire* object is clean, i.e. no validation errors. Something, somewhere is failing validation, so my first step would be to run a project or even solution-wide search for "Name". Unfortunately, you're likely to get a *ton* of false positives for something as general as that, but when you finally find a property or properties with that name, that's most likely your culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i try to replicate your problem and I think the error is not in your ApplicationUser. I think the problem is when you try to create the user. Because in your Person constructor you assign the UserName equal to EMail (*I dont think you need that lines*). But Identity verify the UserName before create the instance. I made the same example as you have, with this lines i got the same error:

```
//With out UserName property
var usertemp = new ApplicationUser() {
    Profile_Id = "admin",
    Email = "rommelmeza@gmail.com",
    FirstName = "Rommel",
    LastName = "Meza",
    Password = model.Password,
    Active = true
};

var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(usertemp, model.Password);
// Error Name cannot be null or empty
```

You need to explicit add the UserName property to this:

```
//With UserName property
var usertemp = new ApplicationUser() {
    Profile_Id = "admin",
    UserName = "rommelmeza@gmail.com",
    Email = "rommelmeza@gmail.com",
    FirstName = "Rommel",
    LastName = "Meza",
    Password = model.Password,
    Active = true
};

var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(usertemp, model.Password);
// Success!!!
```

Its works for me.